# FOREACH LOOP RETURNING DOUBLE RESULTS

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, array-unique

I am outputting results from a table with multiple columns. So I used a foreach loop to loop through but it is returning double results. 
Here is my code:

```
<?php
while($row=$stmt_header->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
?>
    <tr class="odd gradeA">
        <form action='semesters.php' method='post'>

        <?php
        foreach($row as $k)
        {
            echo '<td>'. $k . '</td>';
        }
        ?>

        </form>
    </tr>
<?php
    } ?>....
```

and the output is here...
[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should [edit] this to fix the formatting and always show errors and messages as text in the question. No one wants to go to an image link for that.

Comment: If you can’t guess, what the “both” in `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` means ... then go read up on it!

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` returns both associated and unassociated arrays. Use `PDO::FETCH_ARRAY` or `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` instead.

Comment: The [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) is really simple to read.

Answer (score 3):

Replace PDO::FETCH_BOTH with PDO::FETCH_ASSOC or PDO::FETCH_NUM: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column name **and** 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much. I replaced and it worked for me. I do not know how to thank you......